# Extrude walls from floorplan

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I am trying to import a .dxf file in c# to extrude walls, windows and doors to create a 3D model from a floorplan. Is there any way how this can be done please?

Answer (score 1):

Check out netDxf, a library built for the purpose of loading and examining Autocad files: https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf

Also, in general, you may want to think about how your questions are framed, in this case your title is really not aligned with you question, a title along the lines of "Load and process DXF files in C#" would offer more insight in to what you're trying to do and why it's relevant to these tags.

Comment: Is there any extrusion methods in this library?